# Deleted rasters still appear in geodatabase in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am trying to remove rasters from a geodatabase in ArcGIS Pro 2.2, but the rasters still appear in the catalog and when I run arcpy.ListRasters('*').

However, when I run the delete_management tool, it says that the raster is not present.

Has anyone run into this before, know know how to solve it?

Comment: This may only apply to ArcMap, but have you tried refreshing (right click, refresh) the catalog?

Comment: Yes, but that is a mistake that I would normally make.

Comment: If you are "trying to remove rasters from a geodatabase" using ArcPy, can you provide a code snippet that illustrates precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck, please?

Comment: What happens when you close and restart Pro? There are a number of issues with things not refreshing after a GP tool does something in Pro, including 2.2.

Comment: The raster is still listed in the catalog.